# Can a request parameter extracted from response of previous request have different values when run multiple times - Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Scenario:
We are extracting a value from 1st request and passing it as a parameter for the 2nd request.
The 2nd request is in Loop controller and it is run multiple times, But every time the 2nd request runs , It should take different value. Is there any way to do this.

Eg: Below is the example screenshots for the same. data is the variable which is passed to the second request .When second request is hit multiple times , It should extract different values.

[image: This request 1 , having response values as 1,2,3,4 , which I will be extracting using regex]

[image]

[image]

[image: Both the times within the loop , The Request 2 will have same value , Is there any way I can get different values here]

Answer (score 0):

1. In the [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) set "Match No" to `-1` to you will extract all the matches into:

   ```
   data_1=1
   data_2=2
   etc.
   ```
2. In the [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) set the "Loop Count" to `${data_matchNr}`. This way the controller will iterate as many times as there are matches in the Regular Expression Extractor
3. Instead of `${data}` use `${__V(data_${__intSum(${__jm__Loop Controller__idx},1,)},)}`

More information: [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables)